# MongoUserDetailsService in java config returns null

Tags: mongodb

Anybody can see why I get null when returning Customer?
I'm using java config and are able to connect to DB by my mongoConfig.

But when wants to login it seems the problem is my mongouserdtailsservice.

Thanks

```
   public class MongoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
   {

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws        AuthenticationServiceException
  {
    MongoOperations mongoOperations = null;

    try
    {
        mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "booking");
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MongoException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("email").is(username));
        System.out.println("query ready to go");
        Customer customer = mongoOperations.findOne(query, Customer.class);
        System.out.println("query done");
        System.out.println("user: "+customer);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication failed   for user " + username);

        }
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(customer.getUsername(),   customer.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired,   credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(2));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("query failed");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role)
  {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    return authList;
    }

   public List<String> getRoles(Integer role)
  {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (role.intValue() == 1)
    {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
         roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");

    }
    else if (role.intValue() == 2)
     {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
    }

     return roles;
   }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String>   roles)
    {
     List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
     for (String role : roles)
    {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
   }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

It was a conflict in my MongoUserDetailsService.

Here is the new one which is working well!(OBS! The new log in is with email)

```
@Component
public class MongoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    public MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    private User userDetails;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        try
        {
            mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "booking");
            Customer user = getUserByEmail(email);

            userDetails = new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities(user.getRoleAsInt()));
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return userDetails;
    }

    public List getAuthorities(Integer role)
    {

        List authList = new ArrayList();
        if (role.intValue() == 2)
        {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }
        if (role.intValue() == 1)
        {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }

        return authList;

    }

    public Customer getUserByEmail(String email)
    {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(email));
        Customer customer = mongoOperations.findOne(query, Customer.class);

        return customer;
    }

}
```